# Is given set connected?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Is set $A = \{(x,y):|x|+|y| \leq 5\}$ is connected.  I think it is because we cannot write it as union of two separated sets. But I am not confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is path-connected: if $(x,y)\in A$,$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&A\\t&\mapsto&(tx,ty).\end{array}$$is a path (in $A$) joining $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$. Since $A$ is path-connected, it is connected.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:  Path connected is stronger than connected, so if your set happens to be path connected, then it is connected.  The nice thing about this is path connected is easier to show.

Take two points in your set, and show that you can make a path from one to the other in a continuous way that never leaves the set.   If you draw the shape, there are several easy paths that pop out.

Comment: Thanks for idea of path connection .I understand it too.Is the converse is true means if set is connected then it is path connected.I think it should but just want confirmation.

Comment: No, the converse is false.  Example: The topologists sine wave

Comment: Umm..Ok..I haven't gone that deep.thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Let $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in A$, show that their convex combination is in $A$ as well.

Note that convex set is connected.